# Copy row but increase time (+1 minute) per row

Tags: r, copy, match, dplyr

I have a large dataframe (16819 observations) that contains the date and time, the duration and the rating of TV programmes. It looks as follows:

```r
# Network    Date_Time          Dur_sec      Rating1   Rating2
1 Channel1   2013-01-01 18:02   300          0.0873    0.0184
2 Channel1   2013-01-01 18:10   2700         0.0621    0.0489
3 Channel1   2013-01-01 19:00   1500         0.0391    0.0558
5 Channel1   2013-01-01 19:29   1500         0.0128    0.0891
6 Channel1   2013-01-01 20:00   1260         0.0811    0.0182
7 Channel1   2013-01-01 20:30   4500         0.0481    0.0974
```

Now I would like to copy every row but increase the time by 1 minute for as long as the programme runs. Programma 1 runs for 300 seconds (or 5 minutes), and programme 2 runs for 2700 seconds (45 minutes). The gap between 18:07 and 18:10 is a commercial break and should be ignored. The result should thus look like:

```r
# Network    Date_Time          Dur_sec      Rating1   Rating2
1 Channel1   2013-01-01 18:02   300          0.0873    0.0184
2 Channel1   2013-01-01 18:03   300          0.0873    0.0184
3 Channel1   2013-01-01 18:04   300          0.0873    0.0184
5 Channel1   2013-01-01 18:05   300          0.0873    0.0184
6 Channel1   2013-01-01 18:06   300          0.0873    0.0184
7 Channel1   2013-01-01 18:07   300          0.0873    0.0184
8 Channel1   2013-01-01 18:10   2700         0.0621    0.0489
9 Channel1   2013-01-01 18:11   2700         0.0621    0.0489
10 Channel1  2013-01-01 18:12   2700         0.0621    0.0489
.
.
.
55 Channel1   2013-01-01 18:55   2700         0.0621    0.0489
56 Channel1   2013-01-01 19:00   1500         0.0391    0.0558
```

Etc...

How would I do this? The end goal is to match this data to another dataset that also contains Date and Time variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `uncount()` to expand the data frame and then increment the row using the id variable:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  mutate(Date_Time = as.POSIXct(Date_Time)) %>%
  uncount(weights = (Dur_sec %/% 60) + 1, .id = "cnt") %>%
  mutate(Date_Time = Date_Time + 60*(cnt-1))

     Network           Date_Time Dur_sec Rating1 Rating2 cnt
1   Channel1 2013-01-01 18:02:00     300  0.0873  0.0184   1
2   Channel1 2013-01-01 18:03:00     300  0.0873  0.0184   2
3   Channel1 2013-01-01 18:04:00     300  0.0873  0.0184   3
4   Channel1 2013-01-01 18:05:00     300  0.0873  0.0184   4
5   Channel1 2013-01-01 18:06:00     300  0.0873  0.0184   5
6   Channel1 2013-01-01 18:07:00     300  0.0873  0.0184   6
7   Channel1 2013-01-01 18:10:00    2700  0.0621  0.0489   1
8   Channel1 2013-01-01 18:11:00    2700  0.0621  0.0489   2
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you tell me if this works?

```
df$Date_Time <- as.date(df$Date_Time, format = "%-%m-%Y %H:%M", tz = "CET")
```

I first make sure the time line is properly set, next create a minute variable, mutate the new time and remove 3 minutes if the commercial break was in between the times.

```
df <- df %>%
  mutate(Dur_min = Dur_sec/60) %>%
  mutate(new_date_time = Date_Time + mns(Dur_min)) %>%
  mutate(new_date_time = ifelse(Date_Time <= "2013-01-01 18:07" & new_date_time >= "2013-01-01 18:10", new_date_time - mns(3), new_date_time))
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response! It throws me an error saying that `object 'new_date_time' not found`

Comment: Ah yeah if you use the top one it should work, the short one doesn't because im defining it in the same function ... my response wasn't the one you needed anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way using `complete`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
  mutate(Date_Time = as.POSIXct(Date_Time, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")) %>%
  group_by(row = row_number()) %>%
  complete(Date_Time = seq(Date_Time, by = "1 min", length.out = Dur_sec/60)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-row) %>%
  fill(everything())

#   Date_Time           Network  Dur_sec Rating1 Rating2
#   <dttm>              <fct>      <int>   <dbl>   <dbl>
# 1 2013-01-01 18:02:00 Channel1     300  0.0873  0.0184
# 2 2013-01-01 18:03:00 Channel1     300  0.0873  0.0184
# 3 2013-01-01 18:04:00 Channel1     300  0.0873  0.0184
# 4 2013-01-01 18:05:00 Channel1     300  0.0873  0.0184
# 5 2013-01-01 18:06:00 Channel1     300  0.0873  0.0184
# 6 2013-01-01 18:10:00 Channel1    2700  0.0621  0.0489
# 7 2013-01-01 18:11:00 Channel1    2700  0.0621  0.0489
# 8 2013-01-01 18:12:00 Channel1    2700  0.0621  0.0489
# 9 2013-01-01 18:13:00 Channel1    2700  0.0621  0.0489
#10 2013-01-01 18:14:00 Channel1    2700  0.0621  0.0489
```